# QT integration with openGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a VS project using OpenGL and I'm asking if it's possible to integrate between openGL and my QT interface? How do I use this QT UI to be the OpenGL product UI? Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [QGLWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtopengl.html) or for more complex uses [Accelerate your Widgets with OpenGL](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html)

Comment: This is an excellent sample and I intend to use it myself as it allows me to use QWidgets for GUI elements within my OpenGL 'game'.  One issue, however, is that the QDialogs embedded within the QGraphicsView no longer have a title bar and cannot therefore be moved (the titlebar is there on the screenshot).  I cannot see what's changed or how to correct this.  Can you help Martin?

Comment: IIRC there was a change for 4.6/4.7 that breaks some of the examples. But I haven't tried it

Comment: OK thanks - I'll try and find out what it was - it's very useful to be able to move those controls about.